# Insert a line before match found using sed

Tags: html, sed

I have the following html file head element:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  .....
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <title>Her skrives Tittel. Bruk stilen Title</title>
  <style>
   .....
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .display.math{display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0.5rem auto;}
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

I want to insert the following:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto Serif rel='stylesheet'>
```

before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
```

I have tried this:

```
sed "/^<link.*styles.*/i <link href=\'https:\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Noto Serif rel=\'stylesheet\'>" test.html
```

It did not work.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with `sed`, use `xmlstarlet` or Python, Perl, Ruby

Comment: @GillesQuénot, I believe question is not really about parsing of HTML. Add string before exactly known another string is a task exactly for `sed`, don't you think? I believe `xmlstart` is a bit overkill here.

Answer (score -1):

Check your match template `/^<link.*styles.*/` it's not working because of this `^` real string got spaces at the beginning. Two options here:

1. remove `^`
2. add `[[:space:]]*` like this `/^[[:space:]]*<link.*styles.*/`